# How to change the view from controller in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute, ng-view, angularjs-ng-route

I am new to angular js and trying to work with `ng-view` and `ngRoute` directives.

I have a loginPage.html in which i have code for login button written as follows

```
<button class="button button-block" ng-click="login()">Log In</button>
```

and on clicking the button the login function in loginController will get executed and my controller is written as follows:

```
var App = angular.module('App', ['ngRoute']);

App.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'loginPage.html',
        controller: 'loginController'
      }).
      when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'homePage.html',
        controller: 'homeController'
      });
  }]);

App.controller('loginController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', function($scope, $http) {
    console.log("Hello from login controller");


    $scope.login = function() {
        //console.log($scope.user);
        $http.post('/login', $scope.user).success(function(response) {
            if(response.status == "true")
                //if the response is true i want to go to homepage.html.

            else
                $scope.error="Invalid login! Please try again";
                $scope.user.email="";
                $scope.user.password="";
      });
    };

}]);
```

If the `response.status==true` then i want to change my view to `/home`. Can someone please tell me how to do that?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(response.status == "true")
    $location.path("/home");
```

Don't forget to add `$location` to your controller parameters like this:

```
['$scope', '$http', '$location', function($scope, $http, $location)...
```

Also, wrap your `else` statement in brackets, or else only the first row is inside the statement:

```
else {
    $scope.error="Invalid login! Please try again";
    $scope.user.email="";
    $scope.user.password="";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked!  i forgot to add the $location to the controller parameters

Answer (score 1):

Use `$location.path`:

```
if(response.status == "true") {
    $location.path('/home');
}
```

Also, you have missed adding `$location` in the controller dependancy list:

```
function($scope, $http, $location)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(response.status == "true")
   $location.path("/home");
```